# Bounded handwritten character segmentation in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am involved in Handwritten Character recognition research in MATLAB, the system take the input which is a scanned handwritten character form that looks like this:

[image]

currently, the segmentation done by firstly separate the form row wise and then the separated row will be segmented column wise to produce individual handwritten character. This segmentation done by scanning the image all the way by making use of horizontal and vertical image projection.

I am still not satisfied by this procedure and wonder if there is any alternative in this segmentation process that can reduce the cost of the segmentation process

Answer (score 0):

Using [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html), each character and each rectangle will be extracted as a connected component. Then you could use [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to extract features that can be useful.